# coldfusion10 via war on pre-existing tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, servlets, coldfusion, liferay-6, web.xml

I've deployed the cfusion.war on a pre-existing tomcat instance also hosting Liferay(6.1.x). Both are in the webapps directory. I had to work through some issues related to taglib in the web.xml of the deployed cfusion.war. But it finally deployed without errors.  Now I have the issue that tomcat doesn't know what to do with a .cfm (causing the browser prompting for download of http://my.liferayserver.edu/cfusion/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm instead of rending it with coldfusion). I think I have to do some servlet mapping in the "main" /tomcat/conf/web.xml (not /webapps/cfusion/WEB-INF/web.xml)

I've seen the few blogs, forum posts and other searchable information on this. It looks like CF10 can run fronted by Apache and using mod_jk.so, but I can't do this as it will probably mess with the Liferay instance I'm using ( it's delivered with a vendor's portal product).

Any thoughts on how to configure the pre-existing (not deployed with CF) tomcat instance web.xml to map to CF servlets in the deployed cfusion.war would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen, Tomcat needs a servlet-mapping in the web.xml file, however Tomcat does not support multiple wildcards in a mapping. So you can do

```
<servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_7">
    <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.cfm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But not

```
<servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_7">
    <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.cfm/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Read more here maybe?

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/coldfusion-tomcat.html

Comment: Thanks Tyler, I tried editing the web.xml file in the cfusion war ... same behavior. I've even tried to move some of the servlet mapping from the cfusion/WEB-INF/web.xml to the /tomcat/cof/web.xml .. also to no effect. In this scenario, Tomcat is the web container AND the web server. I think I need to use Tomcat web.xml to ColdFusion. There is a deployment scenario which uses Apache ( with mod_jk.so ) to do this but as this Tomcat is also where I have the Liferay instance, I really dont want to layer Apache on top. It would take my vendor delivered product to far outside "as delivered."

Comment: Then sorry, I can't really even get CF to run on Tomcat. Just thought that might be your issue.